# Worth going the Drupal 7 fields route for a moderate scale image oriented website?

Tags: php, performance, drupal, drupal-7

I am working on this website that catalogues products with their basic information and all. I checked and all the different input features required were possible using a combination of fields(cck) and some related modules, features like multi image upload, multiple field values, dependent fields, node reference. My only fear is this would result in a good number of tables that would effect performance. How serious would that performance hit be is what I am curious about? The website is for a niche segment and wont be expecting thousands of users at the same time, maybe a couple hundred simultaneous users during some promotional event, thats it.

I can code everything from scratch but the last time I tried it in drupal 6, there were a lot many hurdles, specially for ajax based dynamic forms and we are a bit tight on schedule. So i just need some help figuring out if the extra effort would be really worth it.

Thanks.

(ALSO: Why did field/cck have to take a table for each field route instead of a table for a content type? Wouldn't that have been more efficient?)

Comment: This is a very good question but perhaps not really suited for Stack Overflow...You'll likely get a very good response posting it on drupal.stackexchange.com. If you want a moderator to migrate it for you just 'flag' it and say so. Please don't post cross-site though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is alot of ajax functionality out of the box, multi image upload etc ... so that depends on what you need, and if the functionality is allready available.

I have drupal websites with 1000+ visitors a day, with the right caching this is no problem.

The content type fields have their own table now, because they restructured everything to entitys. This makes everything more generic and abstract, so that functionality is now not specific to cck, or one module, but for every module at the same time. Sure this propabely affect the performance, but again, with the right caching enabled this shouldn't be a problem.

Conclussion: Is it worth the effort ? That totaly depends on what you need to create exactly, and how much you can use from existing modules. Also on how often you will have to change things, how large your catalogue ...

Comment: For now its all available. Some that isn't, I can easily incorporate. Thanks for your valuable feedback, I just might give it a shot if others haven't got much to say against it.

Comment: :). You can always message me for a chat if you want to discuss this more. grtz

Comment: hey thanks, surely will but I think I have almost settled for going with the fields api for I posted in the drupal irc channel and that's what some folks recod there as well. With the right caching, its pretty much the same PLUS that drupal 7 takes the load off of db and does more processing on the php end so thats more worth worrying about.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out the Media module suite. While it's not seen a final release as yet and its sub-modules are in a worse state, it's quite usable albeit with rough edges.

Fields use their own tables for efficiency and reusability. This allows a field to be reused in multiple node types. Besides, how would you handle multi-value fields if they were all dumped into a single table per node type?

Performance depends entirely on the type of your audience - anonymous vs. authenticated. If it's anonymous, then you should be fine. If it's authenticated then you will need to pay a little more attention :) Performance for your traffic estimate should not be a problem in a decently capable server.